# create-react-app / Material-UI App Styling Different on Deploy

Tags: reactjs, build, material-ui, web-deployment, create-react-app

I had a certain bug that I was unsure how to debug. The bug is that styling that I use for a `create-react-app` (Typescript) app through material-ui and regular CSS, shows up just fine in development but it shows differently for certain CSS properties when I deploy the app online (I've only tried Heroku and Vercel). The app doesn't show any errors or warnings in the console when I'm developing. I have no idea why it's happening and I've tried the following so far

1. Read through my code many times being extra careful at every step.
2. Open the website (development and production) in incognito mode on Chrome 85.0.4183.83 (Linux, 64 bit)
3. Look through the documentation for material-ui (material-ui.com) and the React docs for any lead on this
4. Search google for prior such issues

So far, nothing has turned up. Could someone please guide me in the right direction?

The build pack I use on Heroku after deployment is the well known one by  mars and available at https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/mars/create-react-app.tgz .

For convenience, I have included my `package.json` [here](https://pastebin.com/JLmREtBw) on pastebin.

Thank you so much for helping out.

============= EDIT =============

I've been experimenting with the code and it seems like the problem lies with how material-ui is compiled during build time. The problems which don't show up in development, show up in production.

For example, the biggest thing I noticed is if you mix custom style prop flags given by the material-ui components and add your own styling with `className` or `style`, during build time these latter styles are overridden partially if not completely.

So if I do

```
import   React,
       { useRef }  from "react";
import {
         Button,
         makeStyle,
         Theme
       }           from "@material-ui/core";
/*
Start of functional component using memo
.
.
.
*/

const useClasses = useRef(makeStyle((theme : Theme) => { return {
      buttonStyles:
      {
          backgroundColor: theme.palette.text.hint
      }
}}));

const styles = useClasses.current();

<Button
    color={"secondary"}
    className={styles.buttonStyles}>
    button text
</Button>
/*
.
.
.
*/
```

in development, the button will have the `backgroundColor` I give it in `makeStyles`, but in production that property will switch to `secondary` as given in the `color` prop which defaults to the value `theme.palette.secondary.main`.

And sometimes, just even using a component from material-ui without any extra config causes a problem.

I am also using code splitting with `lazy` and `Suspense` if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

StackMatch can you please link your github/gitlab repo? I think I might know what the problem is but can't be certain without seeing how your dev environment is configured.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you for the offer to review my code. I'm currently removing any sensitive information and preparing the project for upload to Github. I should have it ready in a few hours and I'll paste the link here. Please let me know when you see it so I can take it down. Please also see the edit I made to my question, that may shed more light on where the problem is.

Comment: Any luck here? Having the same issue.